# 16 programmers were asked if they knew Pascal, C++ and Java. How many of them knew C++ and Java simultaneously but did not know Pascal?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

$16$ programmers were asked if they knew Pascal, C++ and Java.
It turned out that:

- $12$ knew Pascal
- $15$ knew C++
- Java language knew as many programmers as Pascal and C++ knew
  simultaneously,
- $8$ knew pascal and Java.

> How many programmers knew C++ and Java simultaneously but did not know Pascal?

**My approach:**

- A - Pascal
- B - C++
- C - Java

$16 = |A∪B∪C| = |A|+|B|+|C| -|A∩B| - |A∩C|-|B∩C|+ |A∩B∩C|$

We also that $8$ people know both Pascal and Java so $|A∩C|= 8$, and from third fact number of people who know Java is the number who know both Pascal and C++ so $|C| = |A∩B|$.

Back to first equation of $|A∪B∪C| = 16$ we get:

$16 = |A|+|B|+|C| -|A∩B| - |A∩C|-|B∩C| + |A∩B∩C|$

$16 - 12 - 15 - |C| + |C| + 8 = -|B∩C|+ |A∩B∩C|$ (as $|A∩B|=C$ and $|A∩C|= 8$)

$-3$ = -$|B∩C|+ |A∩B∩C|$ What i'm looking for is $|B∩C|$ but to do so I need to have $|A∩B∩C|$ any ideas?

Comment: See [Inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: I think it's going to be important that all but one knows C++.

Comment: My idea was :
A - Pascal

B -C++

C -Java

16 = |A∪B∪C| = |A|+|B|+|C| -|A∩B| - |A∩C|-|B∩C| 

We also know that both Pascal and Java knows 8 people so |A∩C|= 8, and from third fact number of people who know Java is the number who know both Pascal and C++ so |C| = |A∩B|.

Back to first equation of |A∪B∪C| = 16 we get:

16 = |A|+|B|+|C| -|A∩B| - |A∩C|-|B∩C|


16 - 12 - 15 - |C| + |C| + 8 = -|B∩C| ( as |A∩B|=C and |A∩C|= 8)


|B∩C| = 3.

But I forgot about |A∩B∩C| and I don't know how to get it, any ideas?

Comment: Read  your question carefully

Comment: I'm looking for |B∩C| i know that, but to do so I need to find |A∩B∩C|

Comment: |B∩C| contain all programmers that a)only  know C++ and Java and b) know all three languages.Your question exclusively said that  to count only case (a) which is given by |B∩C|- |A∩B∩C|=3.If you want to calculate |B∩C| the information for |A∩B∩C| has to be provided.

Comment: @NewGuy you were right, thank you

Comment: The ones who say they know Pascal were lying. The older ones may have read about it or even used it, but they've completely forgotten now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $x_P$, $x_{PC}$, etc., the number of persons that know exactly P, resp., P and C, etc. I'm assuming that each person knows at least one of the given languages, and that the problem has at least one solution with all $x_\iota$ nonnegative. Then we have the following equations, whereby $(4)$ collects the persons that dont know C${}^{++}$:
$$x_P+x_{PC}+x_{PJ}+x_{PCJ}=12\ ,\tag{1}$$
$$x_J+x_{CJ}+x_{PJ}+x_{PCJ}=x_{PC}+x_{PCJ}\ ,\tag{2}$$
$$x_{PJ}+x_{PCJ}=8\ ,\tag{3}$$
$$x_P+x_{PJ}+x_J=1\ .\tag{4}$$
We use $(3)$ to eliminate $x_{PCJ}$ from $(1)$; furthermore $x_{PCJ}$ can be cancelled in $(2)$:
$$x_P+x_{PC}=4\ ,\tag{5}$$
$$x_J+x_{CJ}+x_{PJ}=x_{PC}\ .\tag{6}$$
Subtracting $(6)$ from $(4)$ we obtain
$$x_P-x_{CJ}=1-x_{PC}\ ,$$
hence $$x_{CJ}=x_P+x_{PC}-1=3\ ,$$
using $(5)$.

Answer (score 1):

as you said:

$16 = |A| + |B| + |C| − |A∩B| − |A∩C| − |B∩C| + |A∩B∩C|$

$-|B∩C| = 16 - |A| - |B| - |C| + |A∩B| + |A∩C| - |A∩B∩C|$

$-|B∩C| = 16 - 12 - 15 - |C| + |C| + 8 - |A∩B∩C|$

$|B∩C| = 3 + |A∩B∩C|$

now we have from the question that from the 16 people who were asked, 15 of them knew c++ so at most 1 person doesn't know c++, the number of people who know java and pascal is 8, so either the person who doesn't know c++ knows both java and pascal or she doesn't. which means :

$ |A∩B∩C| = 8$  or $7$

so your answer can be 10 or 11 since there's no more clues in the question and they're both admissible.

edit:

my answer counted the number of people who know java and c++ (whether they know pascal or not) the answer for people who only know java and c++ is as said in the comments

$|B∩C| - |A∩B∩C| = 3 $

Comment: Actually Anwser is |BnC| - |AnBnC| = 3 since |BnC| are people who know C++ and Java but they may know Pascal so we need to subtract ammount of people who know all of the languages!

Comment: @Michał you're right, my mistake. I didn't pay attention to the `but do not know pascal' part

Comment: Yeah it fooled me as well